# How to properly report aborted suites from SBT, Scalatest and Junit reporter

Tags: junit, sbt, scalatest

I am running Bamboo, SBT (0.13.x) and Scalatest (2.x). I use the Junit reporter like

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-u", "target/junit")
```

However, when a suite is aborted in Scalatest there is no indication (build not failing in Bamboo). Is there another Runner option which I should use to notify the Junit reporter of the aborted suite?

```
16-May-2014 16:29:55    [info] Total number of tests run: 8
16-May-2014 16:29:55    [info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 1
16-May-2014 16:29:55    [info] Tests: succeeded 8, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
16-May-2014 16:29:55    [info] *** 1 SUITE ABORTED **
```